# Does Ankara airport have a transit area?

Tags: transit, layovers, ankara

I'm interested if Ankara Esenboga airport has a transit area where one could conveniently spend time during 6-hour layover.

And if true, is there free Wi-Fi available (without Turkish SIM card or other difficulties)?

Thanks!

Comment: The [airport website says](https://esenbogaairport.com/en-EN/passenger/passenger-guide/page/transfer-transit) that "the passengers who come to our terminal and have domestic or international connections can utilize the services available in the terminal in accordance with the condition of their flight hours" which is pretty hard to parse but I think means there is at least some transit available. Hopefully somebody who knows more can weigh in.